# Cure a lucky bamboo with severe conditions

Tags: container-gardening, office-gardening, lucky-bamboo, bamboo, weeping-willow

My bamboo (lucky) was sitting (in a room without heater or air conditioning). It is in a winter time where the temperature outside now drops to 15 F or -10 C. But the room temperature I think is around 15 C now.

It became like this after a day: *The head goes down suddenly in a day*, when I left home for a day.

How should I do to make the bamboo survives again? (It looks that the bottom still stays green.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think giving it Black Wych beer to drink will revive it, but at least it will die happy ;) Seriously though, the roots don't look completely dead, so just cut off the obviously dead parts, stick it in a pot, KEEP IT WARM, and wait.

Comment: Should I cut some of the roots? (They becomes entangled with each other...?)

Comment: No - just pot it up in something just about big enough to accommodate the roots.